# Fade back DIV on hover- even when hovering over front DIV

Tags: html, css, hover

I'm looking for a CSS only solution to fade an image in a back DIV when hovering over any section of the DIV, including DIVs that are in front of it.

Here is what I've been able to build so far:  http://jsfiddle.net/kqo10jLb/

The CSS:

```
#caseouter {
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
}

#casewrap2 {
    background-color: #000;
}

#casetitle {
    font-size: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
    color: #fff;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

#casethumb {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: -100px;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: .2s opacity ease .2s;
    height: 100px;
}

#casesecondline {
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #666;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    margin-top: -10px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#casethumb img {
    width: 100%;
}


#casethumb:hover {
    opacity: .75;
}

#casetitle:hover ~ #casethumb a {
    opacity: .75;
}

#casesecond:hover ~ #casethumb a {
    opacity: .75;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<div id="casewrap2">
    <div id="casethumb">
        <a href="www.google.com">
            <img src="http://ringer.tv/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/case_bravo.jpg">
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="caseouter">
    <a href="www.google.com">
        <div id="casetitle">Headline</div>
        <div id="casesecondline">Subheadline</div>
    </a>
</div>
```

As you'll see, the back image fades on hover, however, it will not fade when I hover over the headline and subheadline text.  I've tried using `#casetitle:hover ~ #casethumb a` but I'm obviously doing something wrong.  Thanks!

Comment: Any reason against `caseouter` being a child of `casewrap2`?

Comment: Nope.  `casewrap2` is contained by a conditional PHP tag but it's not necessary that it be conditional.  I can remove the conditional tag and place `caseouter` into `casewrap2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're after? http://jsfiddle.net/kqo10jLb/1/

I moved the caseouter into the casewrap2 object and changed the hover to this:

```
#casewrap2:hover #casethumb {
    opacity: .75;
}
```